# Swiftmailer doesn't work in localhost?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am using symfony 3.0 Version:
**Config.yml**

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    port:      %mailer_port%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

**Parameters.yml**

```
mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_port: 25
    mailer_user: pankaj@acb.com
    mailer_password: abc123
```

I run the following command for sending the mail:

```
php Console Swiftmailer:spool:send
```

processing default mailer .... 0 emails sent

```
php Console Swiftmailer:email:send
```

sent 1 emails

app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue:
Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [An attempt was made to
access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  #10013]

I did also try via code:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
                    ->setFrom('pankaj@acb.com')
                    ->setTo('ashish@acb.com')
                    ->setBody('good jb');            
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

But i did not get any exception/error/message.

Anyone can suggest me what can i do ? Thanks

Comment: php version? there are more debug info in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

For testing email when developing, I suggest you to use [mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/). The setup for this tool is:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_port: 1025
```

And then you can verify the emails in your browser: (with the default settings)

```
http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Answer (score 0):

**Config.yml**

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    port:      %mailer_port%
    spool:     { type: memory }
    encryption : "%encryption%"
```

**Parameters.yml**

```
mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: smtp.office365.com
    mailer_port: 587
    mailer_user: abc@domain.com
    mailer_password: 
    encryption : tls
```

I did set following setting in both files.Now its working for me with localhost environment.